# How do you profile DNS response times on CentOS8?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos8

I would like to know how long exactly takes a DNS response to resolve an address - so I can compare different servers (my machine (I use `named`), GCP DNS, other public DNS servers).

The problem is that my app needs to resolve a URL which IP has just changed inside a CDN (e.g. Cloud Flare). And I need this resolve to be as fast as possible.

So I would like to collect statistics on how fast are different DNS servers can resolve a URL to new IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark can provide you DNS statistics on response times.

But it sounds like what you're really asking is something like "If example.com changes their IP address, what service will reflect that new IP the fastest?"  If that really is the question, then the bad news is ALL of them are going to be highly dependent on the TTL example.com uses and caching by whatever DNS service is retrieving the RR from the authoritative servers.

TLDR: You may find no significant difference.

EDIT: Steps to analyzing DNS statistics with Wireshark:

1. Collect some sample data using tcpdump

   tcpdump -i<interface-name-or-"any"-keyword> -vn -s0 -w somefilename.pcap port 53
2. Hit control-C when you have collected enough sample data
3. If necessary scp/sftp somefilename.pcap to a machine with Wireshark. It does NOT have to be run on the same machine.
4. Open the file in Wireshark:

   wireshark somefilename.pcap
5. Go to Statistics->DNS

Comment: wireshark seems complicated without UI.. gonna try. thanks. so by your logic - the DNS server of the CDN which changes the IP in question - is going to be **always** the fastest then?

Comment: That is correct - the authoritative DNS servers for the CDN by definition will have the most current DNS info.  Also, Wireshark is very simple - I'll edit my answer with some steps.